# Better way to use clear/deleteAll on hazelcast IMap

Tags: hazelcast

Sample code used:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
                HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
                HazelcastInstance hz1 = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

                IMap<String, String> map = hz.getMap("map");

                for(int i=0; i < 1000000 ; i++) {
                                String key = "key" +Integer.toString(i);
                                String value = "value"+Integer.toString(i);
                                map.setAsync(key,value);
                }
                 System.out.println("Completed loading to Imap");
                long timeStarted = System.currentTimeMillis();
//map.clear()
//map.evictAll()
                //map.keySet().forEach(key -> map.delete(key));
map.keySet().forEach(key -> map.removeAsync(key));
                long timeComplted = System.currentTimeMillis();
                 System.out.println("time took using clear::"+(timeComplted - timeStarted));
}
```

Clear():
   Completed loading to Imap
   time took using clear:: 302
   CPU consumption is too high (above 200%)

ecictAll():
   Completed loading to Imap
   time took using clear:: 511
   CPU consumption is too high (above 200%)

Delete using each key:
   Completed loading to Imap
   time took using clear:: 81578
   CPU consumption is high (above 200%)

Delete using asyncRemove:
   Completed loading to Imap
   time took using clear:: 9818
   CPU consumption is high (above 200%)

Note: One other thing is if the cache is with 10 Million entries then none of the above works in my local.
      It took forever for { clear()/ evictAll()/ delete by key } and finally fails with out of memory issue.
Below picture is the CPU usage when trying to delete 10 million entries from map.

Comment: Where is the picture of CPU usage? Also, is there a question somewhere?

Answer (score 8):

Your test is not measuring just the time taken to perform [IMap#clear()](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#clear--) (or the other methods you tested): rather, it is measuring how much time [IMap#clear()](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#clear--) took to execute while *at the same time* several other `setAsync` operations were  most probably still executing. This is why you are seeing high CPU usage; it's not because `clear` is CPU intensive, it's because there are still async operations queued up and being executed at the same time. Your tight loop is flooding Hazelcast with asynchronous operations and you have not configured any backpressure. Without backpressure configured (see [1](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/MapStore.html#deleteAll-java.util.Collection-) for that), Hazelcast will just accept any number of incoming async operations and you can hit an `OutOfMemoryException` by just flooding it with requests. In order to better observe each of the 4 methods you tried, it's best to use `set` instead of `setAsync` in your loop, this way it is guaranteed that your map is fully populated and no further operations are happening while clearing the map.

Also, the 4 methods you tried above have quite different semantics:

- [IMap#clear()](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#clear--): Clears the map and invokes [MapStore#deleteAll(java.util.Collection)](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/MapStore.html#deleteAll-java.util.Collection-) on the implementing MapStore which, if connected to a database (for example), will delete the records from that database (from `IMap#clear()` javadoc). This (or `evictAll`) is the preferred way to clear an `IMap`
- [IMap#evictAll()](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#evictAll--): Evicts all keys from this map except the locked ones. If a [MapStore](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/MapStore.html) is defined for this `IMap`, `IMap#deleteAll()` is not called by this method (from `IMap#evictAll()` javadoc).
- with any of the `map.keySet().forEach(...);` variants, a clone of all keys in the map is returned by `keySet` thus increasing memory pressure.

One final word, what you observe with a simple test with 2 `HazelcastInstance`s in the same JVM may be quite different than a real-world deployment with 2 `HazelcastInstance`s on 2 different hosts.

[1](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/MapStore.html#deleteAll-java.util.Collection-) http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9/manual/html-single/index.html#back-pressure

Comment: Thanks Vassilis, I agree with you and realized after trying to clear() in spring context and set.